# Safesub, SafeAdd, SafeDiv, SafeMul

Tags: remix, wallet-transfer

What do I use these buttons for, after deploying my contract successfully - I mean which can I use to:

1. Transfer oken to wallet
2. check balance
3. etc

For example to transfer, :

- Which of them should I use?
- what should I enter as [uint 256 a, uint 256 b]?

[image: These are the buttons I mean]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check if it is the token contract you have actually deployed, it looks like you selected to deploy the library there, & hence these functions

Comment: Thank you, you were right! I appreciate

Answer (score 0):

[image: Corrected and It worked okay . Thanks]

I rechecked  and realised I deployed the wrong file